# Flexbox css unordered list custom styling

Tags: css, flexbox, html-lists

I want to style my unordered list like this one below
[Link to what i want to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jk4r.png)

My structure looks like:

```
<div class="tabs">
 <ul class="tabs__labels">
  <li class="0">
   <a class="active" href="#">
    <img/>
    <div>something</div>
   </a>
  </li>
  <li class="1">
   <a class="" href="#">
    <img/>
    <div>something1</div>
   </a>
  </li>
  ...
 </ul>
</div>
```

Is it a good idea to name the list classes like 0,1 etc. and style them separately to somehow achive this effect? How to use flexbox to get similar effect? Should i group them into rows?

Comment: This looks like a job for [CSS Grids.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

Comment: That's the tool I needed! :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be a start?

```css
.tabs__labels {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tabs__labels li {
  flex-basis: 45%;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tabs__labels li:nth-child(odd) {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.tabs__labels li:nth-child(even) {
  display: flex;
}

.tabs__labels li:nth-child(3),
.tabs__labels li:nth-child(4) {
  flex-basis: 35%;
}

.tabs__labels li a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tabs__labels li:nth-child(1)::before {
  content: 'some text';
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-right: 10px;  
}

.tabs__labels li:nth-child(2)::after {
  content: 'some text';
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin-left: 10px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
 <ul class="tabs__labels">
  <li>
   <a class="active" href="#">S
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a class="" href="#">S
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a class="" href="#">S
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a class="" href="#">S
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a class="" href="#">S
   </a>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a class="" href="#">S
   </a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That was the base I needed! :) Thanks so much :) btw wasn't Blazemonger right that the grid would be better here?

Comment: @PokerCloud As you asked for Flexbox, you got one :) ... there is often more than one way to do things, and since we most of the time only see a fraction of the end result, it is difficult for us to say what is better (and Blazemonger didn't say _better_). As of today, Flexbox has better browser support, but if that is not a concern, go with CSS Grid if you prefer.